# How to find duplicate rows with SQL- GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've a table

```
+----+------------+
| id | day        |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2006-10-08 |
|  2 | 2006-10-08 |
|  3 | 2006-10-09 |
|  4 | 2006-10-09 |
|  5 | 2006-10-09 |
|  5 | 2006-10-09 |
|  6 | 2006-10-10 |
|  7 | 2006-10-10 |
|  8 | 2006-10-10 |
|  9 | 2006-10-10 |
+----+------------
```

I want to group by the **frequency and its count**, for eg:-

Since there's a date `2006-10-08` that appears twice, hence frequency `2` and there is only one date that appears twice , hence total dates `1`.

Another eg:- 
`2006-10-10` and `2006-10-09` both appears 4 times, hence frequency `4` and total dates with frequency 4 are `2`.

Following is the expected output.

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
| Freuency | Total Dates with frequency N   |
+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1       | 0                              |
|  2       | 1                              |
|  3       | 0                              |
|  4       | 2                              |
+----------+--------------------------------+ and so on till the maximum frequency.
```

**What I've tried is the following:-**

```
select day, count(*) from test GROUP BY day;
```

It returns the frequency of each date, ie

```
+------------+----------+
| day        | count(*) |
+------------+----------+
| 2006-10-08 |        2 |
| 2006-10-09 |        4 |
| 2006-10-09 |        4 |
+------------+----------+
```

Please help with the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your query as a subquery:

```
select freq, count(*)
from (select day, count(*) as freq
      from test 
      group by day
     ) d
group by freq;
```

If you want to get the `0` values, then you have to work harder.  A numbers table is handy (if you have one) or you can do:

```
select n.freq, count(d.day)
from (select 1 as freq union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n left join
     (select day, count(*) as freq
      from test 
      group by day
     ) d
     on n.freq = d.freq
group by n.freq;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for the query. It worked like a charm. One question, where can I add a `where` clause in first query? Also what is `d` in first query?

Comment: @user1162512 d is just an alias given to the subquery so you can reference it aka d.day... you can put the WHERE in the sub query, it just depends on what you need to do